# PDF document signing with Google KMS and Entrust certificate

Tags: java, pdf, google-cloud-platform, entrust, google-cloud-kms

I am trying to make a valid signature in a pdf document by using a certificate from CA (Entrust) generated with a private key from Google KMS (private key never goes out from the KMS). 
The certificate chain is made as: [entrustCert, intermediate, rootCert]

Following the part of the code I am using to make this happen:

```java
String DEST = "/tmp/test_file.pdf";
OutputStream outputFile = new FileOutputStream(DEST);

CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate[] chain = new X509Certificate[3];
chain[0] = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(entrustCert);
chain[1] = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(intermediateCert);
chain[2] = (X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(rootCert);
int estimatedSize = 8192;

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(contract);

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, outputStream, '\0');

PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
appearance.setReason(“reason”);
appearance.setLocation("Amsterdam");
appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780), 1, "sig");
appearance.setCertificate(chain[0]);

PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
dic.setReason(appearance.getReason());
dic.setLocation(appearance.getLocation());
dic.setContact(appearance.getContact());
dic.setDate(new PdfDate(appearance.getSignDate()));
appearance.setCryptoDictionary(dic);

HashMap<PdfName, Integer> exc = new HashMap<>();
exc.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, (estimatedSize * 2 + 2));
appearance.preClose(exc);

String hashAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithms.SHA256;

BouncyCastleDigest bcd = new BouncyCastleDigest();
PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, hashAlgorithm, null, bcd, false);

InputStream data = appearance.getRangeStream();
byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"));
byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);

// Creating signature with Google Cloud KMS
KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.create();
AsymmetricSignRequest request = AsymmetricSignRequest.newBuilder()
        .setName("path/of/the/key/in/kms")
        .setDigest(Digest.newBuilder().setSha256(ByteString.copyFrom(hash))) 
        .build();
AsymmetricSignResponse r = client.asymmetricSign(request);
byte[] extSignature = r.getSignature().toByteArray();

// Checking if signature is valid
verifySignatureRSA("path/of/the/key/in/kms", hash, extSignature);

sgn.setExternalDigest(extSignature, null, "RSA");
TSAClient tsaClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle("http://timestamp.entrust.net/...");
estimatedSize += 4192;
byte[] encodedSig = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(sh, tsaClient, null, null, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);
byte[] paddedSig = new byte[estimatedSize];
System.arraycopy(encodedSig, 0, paddedSig, 0, encodedSig.length);
PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
dic2.put(PdfName.CONTENTS, (new PdfString(paddedSig)).setHexWriting(true));
appearance.close(dic2);

outputStream.writeTo(outputFile);
```

This is the function from [Google Cloud - Creating and validating digital signatures](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/create-validate-signatures#kms-howto-sign-java) for the signature verification:

```
public static boolean verifySignatureRSA(String keyName, byte[] message, byte[] signature)
    throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

  try (KeyManagementServiceClient client = KeyManagementServiceClient.create()) {
    com.google.cloud.kms.v1.PublicKey pub = client.getPublicKey(keyName);
    String pemKey = pub.getPem();
    pemKey = pemKey.replaceFirst("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    pemKey = pemKey.replaceFirst("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    pemKey = pemKey.replaceAll("\\s", "");
    byte[] derKey = BaseEncoding.base64().decode(pemKey);
    X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(derKey);
    PublicKey rsaKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(keySpec);

    Signature rsaVerify = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    rsaVerify.initVerify(rsaKey);
    rsaVerify.update(message);
    return rsaVerify.verify(signature);
  }
}
```

Currently I am running in the following issues:

1. Every signature is invalid: The document has been altered or corrupted since the signature was applied.
2. The signature verification from Google is always false.

Comment: Please share an example PDF signed by your code to analyze the exact reason why the signature is invalid. This *may* help to find a way.

Comment: Hi mkl, thank you for your response. You can download the file here https://www.filedropper.com/file-signed-failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Broken message digest value

*Analysis of [file-signed-failed.pdf](https://www.filedropper.com/file-signed-failed)*

In an ASN.1 dump of the contained signature container one issue immediately strikes the eye: The `messageDigest` attribute contains a copy of the signed attributes as they should be, i.e. with a proper `messageDigest` attribute:

```
    <30 5C>
4172   92: . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
    <06 09>
4174    9: . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER messageDigest (1 2 840 113549 1 9 4)
         : . . . . . . . . (PKCS #9)
    <31 4F>
4185   79: . . . . . . . SET {
    <04 4D>
4187   77: . . . . . . . . OCTET STRING, encapsulates {
    <31 4B>
4189   75: . . . . . . . . . SET {
    <30 18>
4191   24: . . . . . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
    <06 09>
4193    9: . . . . . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . contentType (1 2 840 113549 1 9 3)
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . (PKCS #9)
    <31 0B>
4204   11: . . . . . . . . . . . SET {
    <06 09>
4206    9: . . . . . . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER data (1 2 840 113549 1 7 1)
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . (PKCS #7)
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . . . }
    <30 2F>
4217   47: . . . . . . . . . . SEQUENCE {
    <06 09>
4219    9: . . . . . . . . . . . OBJECT IDENTIFIER
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . messageDigest (1 2 840 113549 1 9 4)
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . (PKCS #9)
    <31 22>
4230   34: . . . . . . . . . . . SET {
    <04 20>
4232   32: . . . . . . . . . . . . OCTET STRING    
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . 40 76 BC 3F 05 25 E4 C3    @v.?.%..
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . 27 AD 78 FA 73 31 4C 1B    '.x.s1L.
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . 82 97 3D AA 4E 81 72 D6    ..=.N.r.
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . . 23 3C DD 59 D2 82 81 55                            
         : . . . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . . }
         : . . . . . . . }
```

And indeed, in your code the reason becomes clear:

```
byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);
[...]
byte[] encodedSig = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(sh, tsaClient, null, null, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

**These two calls *must* have the same parameters** (except the added `tsaClient` at second position) because the authenticated attributes (aka signed attributes) retrieved in the first call are the actually signed bytes, so the final signature container must be created with the same inputs to be valid.

(If your variable names had been clearer, that problem might have been spotted earlier.)

Thus, to fix the signed attributes, replace

```
byte[] encodedSig = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(sh, tsaClient, null, null, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

by

```
byte[] encodedSig = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, tsaClient, null, null, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

#### RSA padding

Having worked on fixing the issue above, a new issue turned up, *"Internal cryptographic library error. Error Code: 0x2726"*

*Analysis of [test_file.pdf](http://www.filedropper.com/testfile)*

Decrypting the signature bytes using the public RSA key of the signer certificate resulted in

```
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
```

This clearly does not look like a PKCS1v1.5 padded hash value. Thus, either the alleged signer certificate is wrong and we see essentially garbage or the signature does not use PKCS1v1.5 padding at all but instead PSS padding. The trailing `BC` is an indicator for the latter but garbage may also end in `BC`.

Meanwhile, though, the OP has confirmed:

> the private key generated in Google KMS is 2048 bit RSA key PSS Padding - SHA256 Digest

This indeed explain the issue with the signature: iText 5.x does *not* support RSASSA-PSS. When creating a RSA signature it automatically assumes PKCS1v1.5 padding; in particular in the CMS signature container it generates it denotes that the signing algorithm is RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5. Thus, any validator will fail validating the signature.

The obvious options are to

- either add RSASSA-PSS support by pimping or replacing the iText `PdfPKCS7` class
- or switch to a RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 key.

Comment: I applied your suggestion from but then the value returned from **getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes** is never used so I made the call to GoogleKMS by passing *sh* instead of *hash* but it still fails. 
So I tried to call GoogleKMS with the value of *hash*, then i get the **authenticated attributes** from the external signature returned from GoogleKMS, I set the external digest with these authenticated attributes and I get the **EncodedPKCS7** from the external signature..Unfortunately the outcome is still *the document has been altered or corrupted since the signature was applied*.

Comment: *"but then the value returned from **getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes** is never used"* - you should hash it and use the hash in `AsymmetricSignRequest request`. The authenticated attributes (also known as signed attributes) are what immediately is signed.

Comment: yes, i've also tried that way and the signature returns *Internal cryptographic library error. Error Code: 0x2726*. Here the file http://www.filedropper.com/testfile

Comment: Have you somewhere switched from RSA with PKCS1v1.5 padding to RSASSA-PSS? E.g. did you change the `AsymmetricSignRequest` parameters? Or did you switch a setting like that in you Google KMS settings? Decrypting the signature bytes one gets something that might be explained for RSASSA-PSS but that doesn't match PKCS1v1.5 padding anymore. iText 5.x out-of-the-box cannot handle RSASSA-PSS well.

Comment: I have not changed any parameters in `AsymmetricSignRequest request` but the private key generated in Google KMS is *2048 bit RSA key PSS Padding - SHA256 Digest*. May this be the issue?

Comment: While RSA with PSS padding is better than with PKCS1v1.5 padding, it is not directly supported by iText 5.x. So unless you want to pimp `PdfPKCS7` to also support RSASSA-PSS, you should switch to a Google KMS key with PKCS1v1.5 padding.