# Why does my Java Base64 decode give me different results each run?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, base64, decode, google-cloud-kms

Effectively, this is my code (irrelevant stuff removed):

```java
public enum GoogleCertificateProvider {
    ...

    public byte[] signDigest(Digest digest) {
        AsymmetricSignResponse result = client.asymmetricSign(keyVersionName, digest);
        byte[] signature = result.getSignature().toByteArray();
        return Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(signature);
    }

    ...
}
```

As seen above, I am trying to sign something with GCP's KMS (AsymmetricSignResponse: https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-kms/latest/com/google/cloud/kms/v1/AsymmetricSignResponse.html)

The results range between *"Last unit does not have enough valid bits"* and one of the expected (correct) results:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

Why does Base64.decode do this? How would I be able to figure this out? I've been working on this for about 9 hours today and I still have no clue.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why are you base64-decoding the signature?

Comment: I am trying to get the signature from the AsymmetricSignResponse and decode that to a valid byte array

Comment: It is a byte array. That's what toByteArray() does

Comment: it's a base64-encoded byte array

Comment: Sorry, but what makes you think that?

Comment: It also doesn't make sense to me that an expected result is a CSR. That's not a valid signature.

Comment: I was following a Medium post, which says that Base64 decode was required. I'm guessing that's not the case now?

Comment: @sethvargo I got this result when removing the base64 decode: https://gist.github.com/gear4s/edf810a3f2f73c148226c0d624c23d8d

Comment: That doesn't make sense. The result of an asymmetricSign operation is not a certificate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235164/discussion-between-gear4-and-sethvargo).

Comment: As @sethvargo suggested, did the [stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904171/pdf-document-signing-with-google-kms-and-entrust-certificate) help you resolve your issue?

Comment: @GellaboinaAshishYadav yes, apologies. i had no network in my area and am unable to close this question, but I figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by speaking with a fellow StackOverflower, sethvargo.

His first comment in our discussion was `Why are you base64-decoding the signature?`

I tried a couple of things first when I should have tried that first. It ended up being my answer: I was using base64.decode() on something that was not encoded in base64.