# use google cloud for signing documents

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, certificate, digital-signature, signing

I am trying to use google cloud to store certificates and KMS to generate the keys for pdf certified signatures but I have no idea how to do that.
The current software has key and certificate stored in the YML file and we need the certificate to be trusted by adobe, so a HSM is required and google KMS should provide that, but I can't find any documentation or tutorial about how to actually do it. Could someone please help me?
The service is written in Java 8

Comment: Cloud KMS sign or cypher/decypher the data. Not sure that match your requirement.

Comment: Tou could take a look to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57904171/pdf-document-signing-with-google-kms-and-entrust-certificate)